# How to serve a created tempfile in django

Tags: python, django

I have a remote storage project that when the user requests his file, the django server retrieves and stores the file locally (for some processing) as a temporary file and then serves it to the user with mod x-sendfile. I certainly want the tempfile to be deleted after it is served to the user.

The documentations state that `NamedTemporaryFile` delete argument if set to `False` leads to deletion of the file after that all the references are gone. But when the user is served the `tempfile`, it doesn't get deleted. If I set the delete=True in case of downloading I get the "The requested URL `/ServeSegment/Test.jpg/` was not found on this server."

Here is a view to list the user files:

```
def file_profile(request):
    obj = MainFile.objects.filter(owner=request.user)
    context = {'title': 'welcome',
               'obj': obj
               }
    return render(request, 'ServeSegments.html', context=context)
```

This is the view which retrieves, stores temporarily and serve the requested file:

```
def ServeSegment(request, segmentID):    
    if request.method == 'GET':    
        url = 'http://192.168.43.7:8000/foo/'+str(segmentID)
        r = requests.get(url, stream=True)
        if r.status_code == 200:
            with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(dir=
        '/tmp/Files', mode='w+b') as f:
                for chunk in r.iter_content(1024):
                    f.write(chunk)        
            response = HttpResponse()
            response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; segmentID={0}'.format(f.name)
            response['X-Sendfile'] = "{0}".format(f.name)
            return response
        else:
            return HttpResponse(str(segmentID))
```

I guess if I could manage to return the response inside with a statement and after that, the last chunk was written, it would work as I want, but I found no solution regarding how to determine if we are in the last loop (without being hackish).

What should I do the serve the `tempfile` and have it deleted right after?

Comment: Unless you can send the file in some form that the browser can interpret (such as `base64`) there is no guarantee that the file will get served before you delete it. Keep in mind that returning a response does not guarantee that the browser will have the file by then.

Comment: Not sure what you want, but this package might be useful to you at least for testing `django-ajax-upload-widget`

Comment: @LorenzoPeña So how do I accomplish that? any link I can refer to?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16065694/is-it-possible-to-create-encodeb64-from-image-object

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Any file created by `tempfile` will be deleted once the file handler is closed. In your case, when you exit the `with` statement. The `delete=False` argument prevent this behavior and let the deletion up to the application. You *can* delete the file after its been sent by [registering a signal](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/signals/#django.core.signals.request_finished) handler that will unlink the file once response is sent.

Your example does nothing on the file, so you might want to stream the content directly with [`StreamingHttpResponse`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/request-response/#django.http.StreamingHttpResponse) or [`FileResponse`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/request-response/#fileresponse-objects). But as you said you *"stores the file locally (for some processing)"*, I would suggest thinking on doing the processing without any temporary file created and only work with streams.

Comment: I think signals are the way to go, Actually in my final project I some algorithm like secret sharing which transforms uploaded file into N segments and in downloading phase django sever retrieves the segments and has to duty to combine them, that's the real process which is going to take place, and I presume I'm gonna have to use TempDirectory as well.

Answer (score 7):

Adding a generalized answer (based on Cyrbil's) that avoids using signals by doing the cleanup in a finally block.

While the directory entry is deleted by os.remove on the way out, the underlying file remains open until FileResponse closes it. You can check this by inspecting `response._closable_objects[0].fileno()` in the finally block with pdb, and checking open files with `lsof` in another terminal while it's paused.

**It looks like it's important that you're on a Unix system if you're going to use this solution (see os.remove docs)**

https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.remove

```
import os
import tempfile
from django.http import FileResponse

def my_view(request):
    try:
        tmp = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(delete=False)
        with open(tmp.name, 'w') as fi:
            # write to your tempfile, mode may vary
        response = FileResponse(open(tmp.name, 'rb'))
        return response
    finally:
        os.remove(tmp.name)
```

Comment: Can you explain how this removes the need for signals? Finally will be run at return and FileResponse does not seem to read the file in the constructor.

Comment: Thanks - added some edits. This is a platform dependent solution which could be why you're seeing it fail.

Comment: Thanks for the update. For some reason, this was not happening for me (I use Ubuntu). By using terminal 3 terminals `cat > a.txt`, `tail -f a.txt` and `rm -f a.txt`. I can see you are right, tail continues to update after the file has been removed.

Answer (score 1):

**Disposable files**
Currently your file is being deleted before your read. At the end return

```
f.seek(0)
return FileResponse(f, as_attachment=True, filename=f.name)
```

The temporary file will be closed when the read is complete and therefore deleted.

**Non-disposable files**

For those who stumble across this post and do not have an automatically disposable file handle.

From the other answers, signals seemed to be a reasonable solution however passing data required altering protected members. I was unsure how supported it would be in the future. I also found that whp's solution did not work in the current version of Django.

The most future-proof version I could come up with was monkey patching the file output so the file is deleted on close. Django closes the file handles at the end of sending the file and I can't see that changing.

```
def my_view(request):
  tmp = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(delete=False)

  try:
    # write file tmp (remember to close if re-opening)
    # after write close the file (if not closed)      

    stream_file = open(tmp.name, 'rb')

    # monkey patch the file
    original_close = stream_file.close

    def new_close():
        original_close()
        os.remove(tmp.name)

    stream_file.close = new_close

    # return the result
    return FileResponse(stream_file, as_attachment=True, filename='out.txt')
  except Exception:
      os.remove(output.name)
      raise
```