# Django serve zipped GeoDataFrame shapefile from memeory as download

Tags: python, django, zip, geopandas

I have a Django GIS-related application where users can download shp files. I have the geopandas GeoDataFrame object. I can easily convert it to a zipfile and then read the zipfile to the user when they want to download it:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
import geopandas as gpd
import shapely
import os
from zipfile import ZipFile
def download_shp_zip(request):
    # just some random polygon
    geometry = shapely.geometry.MultiPolygon([
        shapely.geometry.Polygon([ (0, 0), (0, 1), (1, 1), (1, 0) ]),
        shapely.geometry.Polygon([ (2, 2), (2, 3), (3, 3), (3, 2) ]),
    ])
    # create GeoDataFrame
    gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(data={'geometry':geometry}, crs='epsg:4326')
    # some basename to save under
    basename = 'basename'
    #  create folder for this session
    os.mkdir(f"local_folder/{basename}")
    # export gdf to this folder
    gdf.to_file(f"local_folder/{basename}/{basename}.shp")
    # this file now contains many files. just zip them
    zipObj = ZipFile(f"local_folder/{basename}.zip", 'w')
    # zip everything in the folder to the zip
    for file in os.listdir(f"local_folder/{basename}"):
        zipObj.write(f"local_folder/{basename}/{file}")
    # create zip
    zipObj.close()
    # now delete the original files that were zipped
    shutil.rmtree(f"local_folder/{basename}")

    # now we can server the zip file to the user
    filename = f'local_folder/{basename}.zip'
    # check if file exists (just in case)
    try:
        fsock = open(filename, "rb")
    except:
        return HttpResponse(f"File '{basename}' Does Not Exist!",
            content_type='text/plain')
    # create response
    response = HttpResponse(fsock, content_type='application/zip')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = f'attachment; filename={basename}.zip'
    return response
```

This method works, but it saves the file to local storage and then serves it. However, I want to save them to Memory and then serve that to the user instead. I've seen people use os.BytesIO to do something similar. I've been playing around, but I can't quite get anything to work for what I'm looking for.

Again, I have the GeoDataFrame. I want to convert it to a shapefile and then zip it and then serve the zipped folder to the user from Memory without writing it to Local Storage.

Answer (score 5):

It would be possible to create the file and delete it instantly after serving by using [tempfile](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tempfile.html). So not the answer you were looking for but maybe still of help. According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34250008/15353043):

> Any file created by tempfile will be deleted once the file handler is closed. In your case, when you exit the with statement.

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
import geopandas as gpd
import shapely
import os
import tempfile
from zipfile import ZipFile

def download_shp_zip(request):

    # just some random polygon
    geometry = shapely.geometry.MultiPolygon([
        shapely.geometry.Polygon([(0, 0), (0, 1), (1, 1), (1, 0)]),
        shapely.geometry.Polygon([(2, 2), (2, 3), (3, 3), (3, 2)]),
    ])
    # create GeoDataFrame
    gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(data={'geometry': geometry}, crs='epsg:4326')

    # some basename to save under
    basename = 'basename'

    # Convert to shapefile and serve it to the user
    with tempfile.TemporaryDirectory() as tmp_dir:

        # Export gdf as shapefile
        gdf.to_file(os.path.join(tmp_dir, f'{basename}.shp'), driver='ESRI Shapefile')

        # Zip the exported files to a single file
        tmp_zip_file_name = f'{basename}.zip'
        tmp_zip_file_path = f"{tmp_dir}/{tmp_zip_file_name}"
        tmp_zip_obj = ZipFile(tmp_zip_file_path, 'w')

        for file in os.listdir(tmp_dir):
            if file != tmp_zip_file_name:
                tmp_zip_obj.write(os.path.join(tmp_dir, file), file)

        tmp_zip_obj.close()

        # Return the file
        with open(tmp_zip_file_path, 'rb') as file:
            response = HttpResponse(file, content_type='application/force-download')
            response['Content-Disposition'] = f'attachment; filename="{tmp_zip_file_name}"'
            return response
```

Another option would be to use the return statement inside a try-except block and to delete the file in the finally statement:

```
        # Return the zip file as download response and delete it afterwards
        try:
            with open(tmp_zip_file_path, 'rb') as file:
                response = HttpResponse(file, content_type='application/force-download')
                response['Content-Disposition'] = f'attachment; filename="{tmp_zip_file_name}"'
                return response
        finally:
            os.remove(tmp_zip_file_path)
```

For a better user experience, you can use a loading gif until the download is starting.

Comment: I see, so in this solution, you are still writing to an actual file and not to memory, but deleting it instantly after use. How would this work on a server that is performing multiple downloads simultaneously? Wouldn't there be file lock issues? I am currently using a similar solution and I fear that once the app grows, this will become an issue. Thus, I hope there is a way to actually server it from memory and not a file

Comment: Sorry, I didn't realize that the file is not created in memory. I dont know how this would perform on a server with simultaneous downloads, but think it should be allright. According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18550127/how-to-do-virtual-file-processing) you might be able to use a [SpooledTemporaryFile](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tempfile.html#tempfile.SpooledTemporaryFile). However this does not let you create a directory in memory, which is needed to zip the file. Sadly I cannot test this atm as I'm in holidays, but I will come back to this once I'm back.

Comment: Good find! I will try to implement it when I start working again (in about two weeks) and let you know. Otherwise if you beat me to it, lemme know or post another answer!