# how can i screenshot directely base64 in python

Tags: python, base64, screenshot, photo

I would like to screenshot without saving the photo and transform it into base64 to save it in a dictionary.

```
def screen():
    global photo, numero_photo, photo_temporaire, photo_save
    time.sleep(3)
    position_screen = pyautogui.position()
    photo = pyautogui.screenshot(region = (position_screen[0] - 20, position_screen[1] - 20, 40, 40))

    with open(photo, 'rb') as imagefile:
        format_byte = base64.b64encode(imagefile.read())
        format_byte = str(format_byte)
        format_byte = format_byte.lstrip("b'")
        format_byte = format_byte.rstrip("'")
        photo_save.append(format_byte)
    
    print(photo_save)
```

and I have this error:

```
  File "D:\Logiciel\Python\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1921, in __call__        
    return self.func(*args)
  File "d:\Logiciel\programme\projet_bouclette\testbase64_7.py", line 23, in screen
    with open(photo, 'rb') as imagefile:
TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not Image
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already have an `Image` object, not a filename. From the [PyAutoGui `screenshot()` documentation](https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/screenshot.html#the-screenshot-function):

> Calling `screenshot()` will return an Image object (see the Pillow or PIL module documentation for details).

You can convert that object to `base64` by 'saving' it to an in-memory `bytes` object. Adapting an [earlier answer I wrote on the subject](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16066722) to output a PNG image instead (which might be more efficient for screenshots, depending on the subject matter):

```
from io import BytesIO

photo = pyautogui.screenshot(region = (position_screen[0] - 20, position_screen[1] - 20, 40, 40))

output = BytesIO()
photo.save(output, format='PNG')
im_data = output.getvalue()

image_data = base64.b64encode(im_data).decode()
print(image_data)
```

PNG works great for 'regular' image data, such as your average window system on most operating systems. If your screenshots contain video or photo apps, you may want to use `'JPG'` instead of `'PNG'` to save the image in the lossy JPEG format instead.

Whatever you do **do not use `str()` and `strip()` to convert from bytes to strings**. Use `bytes.decode(..)` as I do above. Base64 data is always ASCII-safe so the default codec of UTF8 will do fine.